# Why is my method changing the type of the variable it is handling? How can I stop it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memcached

In `product.rb`, I have:

```
  def active_question_description_for_standard_element_and_index(standard, element, index)
    active_questions_for_standard_and_element(standard, element)[index-1].try(:description)
  end

  def active_questions_for_standard_and_element(standard, element)
    Rails.cache.fetch([self, standard, element, "product_active_questions_for_standard_and_element"]) {
      questions_for_standard_and_element(standard, element).select{|q| q.active}}
  end
```

The `active_question_description_for_standard_element_and_index` method is giving me this error: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'description' for 0:Fixnum`.

So, I start with `self.touch` to bypass the cache and then enter `active_questions_for_standard_and_element(standard, element)`. This returns `0`.

"Huh," I think, "that's meant to return an array, even if it's an empty array. It's not meant to return a Fixnum."

So, I try `questions_for_standard_and_element(standard, element).select{|q| q.active}`, and that returns `[]`, just like you'd expect.

So, why is Rails converting `[]` to `0`? And, how can I stop it?

**UPDATE**

It seems the issue has something do with Rails.cache because when I remove it from the method everything works. So far I don't know what the issue is however, as writing `[]` to the cache works just fine; it does not convert to `0` when read back again.

```
[1] pry(main)> Rails.cache.write('foo', [])
Cache write: foo
Dalli::Server#connect 127.0.0.1:11211
=> true
[2] pry(main)> Rails.cache.read('foo')
Cache read: foo
=> []
```

**UPDATE 2: FOUND THE ANSWER**

Another method was writing to the same cache key. Leaving this hear as a prompt to anyone else who has problems with Rails.cache as this is certainly something worth checking in your debugging.

Comment: Whats the confusion here? type is changing because you are indexing into the array.. `[index-1]` <-

Comment: sorry i left out an important detail; have updated the question

Comment: I have now removed the reference to `[index-1]` as my real problem was that I got the same result without it.

Answer (score 0):

`active_questions_for_standard_and_element` may indeed return an array, but by applying `[index-1]` to it, you are getting an element from that array. Unless your array is meant to contain subarrays, you should not expect `active_questions_for_standard_and_element(...)[index-1]` to result in an array.

Comment: sorry i left out an important detail; have updated the question

Comment: I have now removed the reference to `[index-1]` as my real problem was that I got the same result without it.